# Verifying whether a tree is bst or not Python

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I have a practice interview question which tells me to verify if a tree is a balanced search tree or not and give a verification method... I have the class as

```
Class Node:
def __init__(self, k, val):
    self.key = k
    self.value = val
    self.left = None
    self.right = None
```

and other function definitions for the tree max and min values as

```
def tree_max(node):
    maxleft  = float('-inf') if not node.left  else tree_max(node.left)
    maxright = float('-inf') if not node.right else tree_max(node.right)
    return max(node.value, maxleft, maxright)

def tree_min(node):
    minleft  = float('-inf') if not node.right else tree_min(node.left)
    minright = float('-inf') if not node.left else tree_min(node.right)
    return min(node.value, minleft, minright)
```

My verification method as

```
def verify(node):
    if tree_max(node.left) <= node.value and node.value <= tree_min(node.right):
       if verify(node.left) and verify(node.right):
           return True
       else:
           return False
    else:
        return False
```

My problem occurs when I try to implement the verification method I seem to always get false even when I try to make a BST tree. My implementation is as follows:

```
root= Node(10, "Hello")
root.left = Node(15, "Fifteen")
root.right= Node(30, "Thirty")

print verify(root)

root = Node(10, "Ten")
root.right = Node(20, "Twenty")
root.left = Node(5, "Five")
root.left.right = Node(15, "Fifteen")

print verify(root)
```

Both are giving me False...Is there a problem with my verification function or my min/max function...Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Should the tree be balanced or not? Because usually BST = *Binary* search tree and not *Balanced* search tree. Your algorithm doesn't seem to check if the tree is balanced...

Comment: I think the problem is related to the fact that `node.value` is a string and you are using `float('-inf')` as sentinel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see four errors in your code.

1. First, your check for null children is backwards in `tree_min`. That is, you're checking if `node.right` exists before accessing `node.left`, and vise versa.
2. Second, `tree.min` returns negative infinity when called on a leaf node. You need to use positive infinity in the min calculation (negative infinity is correct in the max version).
3. Third, you have a logic error within `verify`, as it unconditionally calls `tree_min` or `tree_max` and itself on it's child nodes, even if one or both of them are `None`. I suggest making all the functions handle being passed `None`, rather than relying on the caller to do the right thing. This also simplifies the `min` and `max` code a bit!
4. Lastly, you're doing your comparisons on `node.value`, which is the string you're giving each node. I suspect you want to be comparing using `node.key` instead. Comparing a float (like `float("-inf")`) to a string (like `"ten"`) is an error in Python 3, and even in Python 2 where it is legal, it probably doesn't work like you would expect.

With those issues fixed, I get expected results when I create valid and invalid trees. Your two examples are both invalid though, so if you were using them to test, you will always get a `False` result.

Finally, a couple of minor style issues (that aren't bugs, but still things that could be improved). Python supports chained comparisons, so you can simplify your first `if` statement in `verify` to `tree_max(node.left) <= node.key <= tree_min(node.right)`. You can further simplify that part of the code by connecting the checks with `and` rather than nesting an additional `if` statement.

Here's a version of your code that works for me (using Python 3, though I think it is all backwards compatible to Python 2):

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, k, val):
        self.key = k
        self.value = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def tree_max(node):
    if not node:
        return float("-inf")
    maxleft  = tree_max(node.left)
    maxright = tree_max(node.right)
    return max(node.key, maxleft, maxright)

def tree_min(node):
    if not node:
        return float("inf")
    minleft  = tree_min(node.left)
    minright = tree_min(node.right)
    return min(node.key, minleft, minright)

def verify(node):
    if not node:
        return True
    if (tree_max(node.left) <= node.key <= tree_min(node.right) and
        verify(node.left) and verify(node.right)):
        return True
    else:
        return False

root= Node(10, "Hello")
root.left = Node(5, "Five")
root.right= Node(30, "Thirty")

print(verify(root)) # prints True, since this tree is valid

root = Node(10, "Ten")
root.right = Node(20, "Twenty")
root.left = Node(5, "Five")
root.left.right = Node(15, "Fifteen")

print(verify(root)) # prints False, since 15 is to the left of 10
```